# Functions: Find $f(2020,2020)$

Tags: functions

> A function $f$ is defined for non-negative integers $x$ and $y$ such that
>
> $f(0,x)=x+1$
>
> $f(x,0)=f(x-1,1)$
>
> $f(x+1,y+1)=f(x,f(x+1,y))$
>
> Find $f(2020,2020)$.

My Research:

$f(1,0)=f(0,1)=2$

$f(1,1)=f(0,f(1,0))=3$

$f(1,x)=x+2$

Carrying on with the same logic,

$f(2,x)=2x+3$

$f(3,x)=2^{x+3}-3$

$f(4,x)=2^{2^{2^...^2}}-3$ ($x+3$ layers)

However, there is no way for me to continue calculating all the way up to $f(2020,x)$.
Is there a better way to solve this question?

Comment: This won't be valid for $x = 0$ because it says $x$ is positive, not non-negative

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan But where is it used for $x=0$?

Comment: To find $f(1,1)$ requires putting $x=y=0$ in the third property, no?

Comment: Yes, right. We only have $f(1,1)=f(2,0)$ by the second property for $x=2$.

Comment: This is insanely big. It can be written as $\uparrow$ symbol.

Comment: Tried writing python code to calculate this.. don't have enough memory to compute.beyond f(3,3). What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: this is not feasible.

The function you define is the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), the most well-known example of a computable but not primitive recursive function. Informally, it grows too fast to be primitive recursive.

The number $f(2020,2020)$ is stupidly large, much larger than the number of particles in the observable universe, and well beyond the capabilities of any existing computer.

You can play around with the value of the Ackermann function at small inputs [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=fecbfa88f364df34c32702b62f11a7d9). The word "small" should be emphasized, as $f(4,4)$ is already too large to represent.